# CO currency for settlement process in CJ88

Tags: customization, sap-erp

We have an issue with settlement in SAP.

If we post 1000CAD in settlement rule (cj02) for an asset #123456 to a project then it get settled 1000USD after settlement run.
But my question is why the CAD allocation is settling as USD? How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

All transactions (incl. settlements) in CO-PA are done in Controlling Area currency that couldn't be changed. It seems that your CA currency is USD.

Check if flag *All currencies* is set in tcode OKKP, node *Activate component indicators*

[image]

If this is the case then your company uses different currencies for documents which are:

- controlling area currency
- object currency (=company code currency)
- transaction currency (specified for each transaction).

By default all settlements are reconciled in company code currency so check if it is USD and change to desired value.

By and large, currency determination in CO-PA is very complex, check SAP note [1320586](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/1320586) for more details.